# Formik not applying checkbox initial values ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am tring to `enableReinitialize` a `Formik` with `initialValues` but its only applying the text and files fields but not the checkboxes

this is how my initialValues look like

```
{
    "8ee6ff20-b305-42b7-b1fe-94e5615ef583": "4534543",
    "d0682df8-71ce-44d5-ac92-9da5fd0de32d": "Testing",
    "CustomerRequestPage.dbd9163c-dcfe-4c45-aa2a-7794ad1086eb": true,
    "CustomerRequestPage.5ff334b0-48f2-4176-9299-f9a45055ecdc": false,
    "CustomerRequestPage.92a7f37a-7460-44f7-b3c6-e9ab3aa93976": false
}
```

I have a Formik tag with a form, and I am displaying a custom field component.

these 2 values are for a text field and they are getting populated

```
"8ee6ff20-b305-42b7-b1fe-94e5615ef583": "4534543",
"d0682df8-71ce-44d5-ac92-9da5fd0de32d": "Testing",
```

but the checkbox values are not.

```
  <Formik
    validateOnChange
    initialValues={initialValues}
    validationSchema={toFormikValidation(allQuestions)}
    onSubmit={updateCustomFields}
    enableReinitialize
  >
    {({ isValid, dirty }) => {
      const disabled = !dirty || !isValid;
      return (
        <Form>
          {
          flow(
            uniqBy('customField.id'),
            map(({ customField }) => <CustomField toggleKey='CustomerRequestPage' toggleFields={toggleFields} {...customField} />),
          )(allQuestions)
        }
          <Button wide primary disabled={disabled} loading={loading} type='submit'>Save Supporting Information</Button>
        </Form>
      );
    }}
  </Formik>
```

and the CustomField component looks like

```
  switch (type) {
    case 'file_upload':
      return <FileUploadField required={required} name={name} label={label} description={description} onlyOne={!allowMultipleUploads} />;

    case 'text':
      return <Field type='text' placeholder={`Enter ${label}`} required={required} name={name} label={label} description={description} />;

    case 'toggle':
      return (
        <>
          <Checkbox id={toggleKeyValue} name={toggleKeyValue} onClick={(e) => { setIsToggled(!isToggled); }}>
            <BodyText>{label}</BodyText>
          </Checkbox>
          {toggleFields && <DummyDiv />}
          {forToggle.type === 'text' && isToggled && (
            <Field type='text' placeholder={`Enter ${label}`} name={name} description={description} />
          )}
          {forToggle.type === 'file_upload' && isToggled && (
            <FileUploadField name={name} description={description} onlyOne={!forToggle.allowMultipleUploads} />
          )}
        </>
      );

    default:
      return null;
  }
```

this is populating text and file upload fields but not checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very silly mistake, but Formik won't accept such a pattern when populating the fields.

```
"CustomerRequestPage.5ff334b0-48f2-4176-9299-f9a45055ecdc"
```

I remove the `.` and make it `-`,

```
"CustomerRequestPage-5ff334b0-48f2-4176-9299-f9a45055ecdc"
```

so it worked while making the key for the Checkbox as well as in initial values.